# HuggingFace autotrain for entity recognition?

Tags: nlp, named-entity-recognition, pre-trained-model, huggingface, huggingface-trainer

I'm trying to fine tune an entity recognition model on HuggingFace using their autotrain feature, but once I select autotrain, 'Token classification' is the only option available, but that's not what I need.

How do I fine tune an NER model?

Comment: NER can be done with token classification.

Comment: @cronoik That task takes only CONLL format inputs right? So do I need to convert my existing file which is JSONL to CONLL?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know that.

Comment: I spoke to someone who said that CONLL works. Still have to give it a shot though.